# What's the Best way to reuse jQuery?

Tags: jquery, onload, document-ready

Ok, there are so many approaches, however, I am only interested in 1, but which approach to use?  Dunno...

Basically, here's the dilemma.  There will be subsequent calls to jQuery within the body of a page.  It will need to know if jQuery has already been defined previously, and if so, don't reload it, but if not, than load jQuery.  Now, on top of that I need to not run any jQuery code until jQuery is actually sure to be defined.

Here's what I've been using but it's flawed in the sense that I am getting an error on subsequent calls to this in Google Chrome (states that jQuery is not defined)

Here's my code:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = false;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];

   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

function dpmodPollBgColor()
{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        $.cssHooks.backgroundColor = {
            get: function(elem) {
                if (elem.currentStyle)
                    var bg = elem.currentStyle["backgroundColor"];
                else if (window.getComputedStyle)
                    var bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,
                        null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
                if (bg.search("rgb") == -1)
                    return bg;
                else {
                    bg = bg.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
                    function hex(x) {
                        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
                    }
                    return "#" + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]) + hex(bg[3]);
                }
            }
        }

        $(".bar-container").each(function() {
            if($(this).children(":first").css("width") != "0px")
            {
                var hexColor = $(this).children(":first").css("background-color");
                var bgColor = shadeColor(hexColor, 50);
                $(this).css({"background-color": bgColor});
            }
        });
    });
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", dpmodPollBgColor, false);
else
    addLoadEvent(dpmodPollBgColor);
```

I don't want to use `onReadyStateChange` because I don't want it interfering with, what could be, other AJAX calls on that same page.

Basically, I need a method to GUARANTEE that 1.  If jQuery is not loaded, it will load it.  2.  It will not perform the function that jQuery is inside until jQuery has actually been finished loading.  3. It will not interfere with any other jQuery code on the page, no matter what variable is being defined for jQuery.  For example if some other code is defining jQuery as `usin`, instead of the default `$`.

I find myself having extreme difficulty getting multiple instances of jQuery to work in harmony with each other.

The method I am using now is this:

1. Use the if statement that defines jQuery if not loaded via the `if(!window.jQuery)` statement.
2. Define a function, and wrap all jQuery inside of this function:

   function FunctionName()
   {
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   // All jQuery code in here;

   });
   }
3. Attempt to load the function onLoad, using if `window.addEventListener` if possible, otherwise a built-in function called `AddLoadEvent()`

There is a flaw in the implementation somehow, but the logic seems right to me.  How would I go about getting this working on multiple instances of the same code, with different function names, in Google Chrome?  Seems fine in all other browsers, cept Google Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: I would use requirejs or similar for this.

Comment: requirejs??  Never heard of it.  Is there a link?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: Just test if `(window.jQuery)` exists.

Comment: Why not just load jQuery in the head via a normal script tag, and then you don't have to worry about this? You're not loading it asynchronously anyways, so what's the point?

Comment: I dunno.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to load it within the body.  I don't have access to the head!  Can't get head, lol ;) But even if you have it defined in the head you still have the problem of the variable name `$`, if defined elsewhere as something else.  What the hell is `jQuery.noConflict` for anyways?

Answer (score -2):

You have serius mistakes. Here some of them:

**The method I am using now is this:
Use the if statement that defines jQuery if not loaded via the if(!window.jQuery) statement.**

Of course it will give you an error since JQuery object does not exist. You trying to use JQuery object when you dont have the even JQuery file yet.

```
if(!window.jQuery)//requesting JQuery object but..
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = false;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";//here is when you are loading its file.
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];

   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}


****Define a function, and wrap all jQuery inside of this function:**

    function FunctionName() { jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    }); }*
```

*

For what for would someone on earth wrap the `.ready()` function inside a function?? `.ready()` function was made for what its name represent: **when document is ready** not to put it inside a function.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to my question?

Comment: which means that, whenever you reload the page, always give you false. So, innecesary code.

Comment: @Ligth right, but this code might get ran some time inbetween page loads, multiple times, without knowing whether or not jQuery has been included. That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: Of course there is not, just that you are validating something that will always give false if you reload the page.

Comment: So, there's no way to do this than, right?  Is that what you are both saying?

Comment: So glad that you managed to have a conversation with everyone but the one who asked the question.  Not to mention that your answer is not an answer at all.  So, basically, your answer quotes what I said, and just tells me that it's wrong.  Thanks for nothing!